# Alternate letters in a string - code not working

Tags: python

I am trying to make a string alternate between upper and lower case letters. My current code is this:

```
def skyline (str1): 

    result = ''
    index = 0

    for i in str1:
        result  += str1[index].upper() + str1[index + 1].lower()
        index += 2

    return result
```

When I run the above code I get an error saying `String index out of range`. How can I fix this?

Comment: do `for i in str1[:-1]:`

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3):

One way using below with `join` + `enumerate`:

```
s = 'asdfghjkl'
''.join(v.upper() if i%2==0 else v.lower() for i, v in enumerate(s))
#'AsDfGhJkL'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would rewrite your logic:

```
from itertools import islice, zip_longest

def skyline(str1): 

    result = ''
    index = 0

    for i, j in zip_longest(str1[::2], islice(str1, 1, None, 2), fillvalue=''):
        result += i.upper() + j.lower()

    return result

res = skyline('hello')

'HeLlO'
```

**Explanation**

- Use `itertools.zip_longest` to iterate chunks of your string.
- Use `itertools.islice` to extract every second character *without building a separate string*.
- Now just iterate through your zipped iterable and append as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try `for i in range(len(str1)):` and substitute `index` for `i` in the code. After, you could do

```
if i % 2 == 0:    result += str1[i].upper()
else:     result += str1[i].lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

For every character in your input string, you are incrementing the index by 2. That's why you are going out of bounds.

Try using **length of string** for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

you do not check if your index is still in the size of your string.

It would be necessary to add a condition which verifies if the value of i is always smaller than the string and that i% 2 == 0 and that i == 0 to put the 1st character in Upper

with i% 2 == 0 we will apply the upper one letter on two

```
for i, __ in enumerate(str1):
    if i+1 < len(str1) and i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
        result  += str1[i].upper() + str1[i + 1].lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify as minimal as possible in your code, so that you could understand properly. I just added a for loop with step 2 so that you wouldn't end up with index out of range. And for the final character in case of odd length string, I handled separately.

```
def skyline (str1): 

    result = ''
    length = len(str1)
    for index in range(0, length - 1, 2):
        result  += str1[index].upper() + str1[index + 1].lower()

    if length % 2 == 1:
        result += str1[length - 1].upper()

    return result
```

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. One question Karthikeyan, how come you did not need to assign index = 0 at the beginning of your code? Like the way I did in my original code?

Comment: Its ok, I understand now. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```py
def myfunc(str1):
    result=''
    for i in range(0,len(str1)):
        if i % 2 == 0:    
            result += str1[i].upper()
        else:     
            result += str1[i].lower()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

in your code you are  get 2 word by one time so you should divide your loop by 2 because your loop work by depending your input string  so make an variable like peak and  equal it to len(your input input) then  peak = int(peak/2) it will solve your pr

```
def func(name):
counter1 = 0
counter2 = 1
string = ''
peak = len(name)
peak = int(peak/2)



for letter in range(1,peak+1):
    
    string += name[counter1].lower() + name[counter2].upper()

    counter1 +=2
    counter2 +=2

return string
```